# Clnt is not declared. Why?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    If txtBookID.Text.Length = 0 Or txtAuthor.Text.Length = 0 Or _
       txtTitle.Text.Length = 0 Or txtPurchasePrice.Text.Length = 0 Or _
       txtSalePrice.Text.Length = 0 Or txtInventory.Text.Length = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter all data.")
        Dim aBook As New clsBook(txtBookID.Text, txtAuthor.Text, _
        txtTitle.Text, CDec(txtPurchasePrice.Text), CDec(txtSalePrice.Text), _
        Clnt(txtInventory.Text))
        aBook.Add()
        lblNumberRecords.Text = books.Count
        MessageBox.Show("Record added to the database.")
        btnClear.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's funny that even the syntax highlighter on this very site shows the error by not highlighting it as a keyword.

Comment: FWIW: I would get accustomed to the [`AndAlso` and `OrElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operators as short-circuiting conditionals are often nice, and *please* consider indenting continued lines. It makes the code *much easier* to read.

Comment: Clnt Eastwood just left the building.  Taking Else with him.

Answer (score 5):

The second character in your code is a lowercase "L", but it should be a capital "i".

```
Clnt 'current
CInt 'correct
```

Comment: where is that second character ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
If txtBookID.Text.Length = 0 Or txtAuthor.Text.Length = 0 Or _
   txtTitle.Text.Length = 0 Or txtPurchasePrice.Text.Length = 0 Or _
   txtSalePrice.Text.Length = 0 Or txtInventory.Text.Length = 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter all data.")
    Dim aBook As New clsBook(txtBookID.Text, txtAuthor.Text, _
      txtTitle.Text, CDec(txtPurchasePrice.Text), CDec(txtSalePrice.Text), _
      CInt(txtInventory.Text)) 'note CInt and not Clnt
    aBook.Add()
    lblNumberRecords.Text = books.Count
    MessageBox.Show("Record added to the database.")
    btnClear.PerformClick()
End If
```

The function "c***I***nt" was spelled "c***L***nt".

Comment: Well, "what changed"? (Pretend I don't know what I'm looking for :-)

Comment: Yours said "C L N T" the spelling is "C I N T".

Comment: It's not for me -- just a useful part of the answer.